# MongoDB: A complex query with array input

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I'm stuck at finding a solution for the following query.

1) a user can select many categories and subcategories.

2) the user can see all other users how are selected the same categories and subcategories within a certain radius.

Here is the `Schema` of the user

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    image: { type: String, default: 'NA' },
    firstName: { type: String, default: 'first name' },
    lastName: { type: String, default: 'last name' },
    email: { type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true, trim: true },
    password: { type: String, min: 6 },
    gender: { type: String, emun: ['male','female','other'] },
    about: { type: String, default: 'about you' },
    address: {
      zipCode: { type: Number, default: 000000 },
      place: { type: String, default: 'place' },
      street: { type: String, default: 'street' },
      country: { type: String, default: 'Country' },
      location: {
        type: { type: String, default:'Point'},
        coordinates: { type:[Number], index:'2dsphere', default:[0,0] }
      }
    },
    interests: [
      {
        _id : false,
        category: {
          id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
          name: { type: String }
        },
        subCategory: [
          {
            _id : false,
            id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Subcategory' },
            name: { type: String }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
);
```

In my controller here is what I tried

```
homeData: async (req, res, next) => {
    const limit = Number(req.params.limit);
    const { latitude, longitude, minDistance, maxDistance } = getUserCurrentLocation(req);

    const usersWithSameInterests = await User.aggregate([
     {
       "$geoNear": {
          "near": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [longitude, latitude]
          },
          "distanceField": "distance",
          "minDistance": minDistance,
          "maxDistance": maxDistance,
          "spherical": true,
          "query": { "location.type": "Point" }
        }
      },
      {
        "$match": { "interests": { "$elemMatch": {name: 'Sports'} }} // hard coded for testing
      },
      { "$sort": { "distance": 1 } },
      { "$limit" : limit },
      {
        "$project": {
          "_id": 1,
          "image": 1,
          "firstName":1,
          "lastName":1,
          "distance": 1,
          "createdAt": 1
        }
      }
    ]);

    return respondSuccess(res, null, {
      newNotification: false,
      usersWithSameInterests: usersWithSameInterests
    });
  },
```

The response i'm getting is

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "query was successfull",
  "data": {
      "newNotification": false,
      "usersWithSameInterests": []
  }
}
```

Sample categories and subcategories
Category: Sports
Subcategories: Cricket, Football, Hockey, Tennis

Category: Learning Languages
Subcategories: English, German, Spanish, Hindi

looking forward for much-needed help.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a few mismatched columns.

On the `$geonear` pipeline, the line `"query": { "location.type": "Point" }` should be: `'query': {'address.location.type': 'Point'}`.

And on the `$match` pipeline, the line `{ "interests": { "$elemMatch": {name: 'Sports'} }` should be `'interests': { '$elemMatch:' {'category.name': 'Sports'}  }`

**Edit**:

To match multiple interests on the category and subcategory field, You can use the `$in` operator on the `$match` pipeline. Like this:

```
{
  'interests.category.name': { $in: ['Sports'] },
  'interests.subCategory.name': {$in: ['Soccer']}
}
```

It'll return anyone that have Sports in the category name, and Soccer on subcategory name.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I did a bit debugging and figured out the mismatched columns, the real hiccup is having one user having multiple interests. EX: if the logged in user has 1+ interests `Sports, Traveling, Music` then the `$elemMatch ` should look for an array. how do we achieve that? and how do we query both category and subcategory? please do update your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I guess that the $in operator will help on this. You can see more about it on [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)